# -[MPTransportButton _isChargeEnabled]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4bf6cb0

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play a video. The videoplayer will shown as `presentModalViewController`. If the video is finished and the view is dismissed. I get the error :

```
 -[MPTransportButton _isChargeEnabled]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4bf6cb0
```

But I have no idea, where the error comes.

Thanks in advance.

Greeting,

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says: object of class `MPTransportButton` whose value was stored at `0x4bf6cb0` has been released and then used again.

So, you need to find object of type `MPTransportButton` that was released and then reused.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it doesn't really help explain why the MPTransportButton (apparently a private Class from Apple) would still have a reference to it.  Take a look at jotaefe's and my own answers for some more insight into that question.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to dismiss the video player several times when removing the modal?

Make sure your un-register from all notifications before dismissing the player view too (MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, ...)

```
- (void)closeVideoPlayer
{
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];  

       if (mp)
       {                
            [mp stop];
            [mp.view removeFromSuperview];
            mp = nil;       

            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
        }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Related to jotaefe's answer: check to make sure that your MPMoviePlayerController's view isn't still in the hierarchy after the MPMoviePlayerController has been released.  This situation could leave dangling references to some of your MPMoviePlayerController's views subviews which in turn could yield your zombie "message sent to deallocated instance" error.