# iOS App crash issue `[UIWindow warpPoint:]`

Tags: objective-c, ios

I found a weird crash issue in my app, and I can't got enough message from the crash report.

Here is the crash report:

```
 -[TileLayer _isChargeEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14aeadb0
(null)
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x376298a7 __exceptionPreprocess + 186
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3169e259 objc_exception_throw + 32
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x3762ca9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 174
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x3762b915 ___forwarding___ + 300
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x37586650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   UIKit                               0x30775e43 -[UIWindow warpPoint:] + 686
    6   UIKit                               0x3075c1ff _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 2438
    7   GraphicsServices                    0x3777922b PurpleEventCallback + 882
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x375fd523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x375fd4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x375fc313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x3757f4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x3757f36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x37778439 GSEventRunModal + 136
    14  UIKit                               0x3078bcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
    15  Movie                               0x00022eb3 _mh_execute_header + 7859
    16  Movie                               0x00022e40 _mh_execute_header + 7744
)
```

Comment: Please, be more descriptive on the iOS Version and on where exactly the Error appears. This helps people to actually answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it means you tried passing a message (a.k.a calling a method) `_isChargeEnabled` to an object of class TileLayer, but it is non-existent.

**UPDATE**
I did a quick google search and turns out `_isChargeEnabled` is private API of Apple. You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075134/uiwebview-load-crash-nscfdictionary-ischargeenabled) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644930/mptransportbutton-ischargeenabled-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-0x4b) for more information.

Comment: But there's no such method in my code. I guess it's a method in UIKit.

Comment: Updated my answer! Are you using `MPMoviePlayerController`? Those links I provided might be relevant.